# Wierd looking markings in app Android 4.3 Xperia Z

Tags: android, margins, sony-xperia

When I installed my app on a Sony Xperia Z I've got this weird markings on the layout, it's marking padding, and margins.

**"Clean" Screenshot with no issues from a Xperia S**

[image: Screenshot from Xperia S]

**Screenshot from an Xperia Z with weird markings.**

[image: Screenshot from Xperia Z]

Any idea why it's like on the 2nd screenshot? How can I remove it?

Comment: I didn't put much effort in this question FYI.

Comment: There are options to show/hide the margins in the phone's developer settings, have you checked if they are enabled on the Xperia Z?

Comment: I disabled the developer settings, then restarted the app without any change. I'll try rebooting @Lennart